# catch git output from flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to roll out a quickie flask app to get git statistics from a certain repo for coworkers to see.

```
import os, sys

from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/git')
def zooi():
    out = os.popen('git -C /mygitrepo status').read()

    return Response(out, mimetype='text/html')
```

But going to http://127.0.0.1:5000/git does not give any output, and also no error so git is found and started.
This does show output:

```
out = os.popen('echo test').read()
```

and this:

```
out = os.popen('gitxxx status').read()
```

emits:

> 'gitxxx' is not recognized as an internal or external command

how do I catch output from git from python / flask?

This on windows BTW

Comment: Is what `git -C /mygitrepo status` output legal HTML?

Comment: Weird, it is just text. Linebreaks will not show correctly since they are just `\n` not `<br>`, so try wrapping it like this: `f'<pre>{out}</pre>'`; Path to git project correct?

Comment: the path is correct, it just gives no output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's working with subprocess.check_output:

```
m = subprocess.check_output('git status', shell=False)
```

note that shell must be set to False